# What's the most resource efficient way to count how many files are in a directory?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, ls

CentOS 5.9

I came across an issue the other day where a directory had a lot of files.  To count it, I ran `ls -l /foo/foo2/ | wc -l`

Turns out that there were over 1 million files in a single directory (long story -- the root cause is getting fixed).

My question is: is there a faster way to do the count?  What would be the most efficient way to get the count?

Comment: `ls -l|wc -l` would be off by one due to the total blocks in the first line of `ls -l` output

Comment: @ThomasNyman It would actually be off by several because of the dot and dotdot pseudo entries, but those can be avoided by using the `-A` flag. `-l` is also problematic because of the reading file meta data in order to generate the extended list format. Forcing NOT `-l` by using `\ls` is a much better option (`-1` is assumed when piping output.) See [Gilles's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90152/1925) for the best solution here.

Comment: @Caleb `ls -l` doesn't output any hidden files nor the `.` and `..` entries. `ls -a` output includes hidden files, _including_ `.` and `..` while `ls -A` output includes hidden files _excluding_ `.` and `..`. In [Gilles's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90106/whats-the-most-resource-efficient-way-to-count-how-many-files-are-in-a-director/90152#90152) the bash `dotglob` [shell option](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) causes the expansion to include hidden files _excluding_ `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Short answer:

```
\ls -afq | wc -l
```

(This includes `.` and `..`, so subtract 2.)

---

When you list the files in a directory, three common things might happen:

1. Enumerating the file names in the directory. This is inescapable: there is no way to count the files in a directory without enumerating them.
2. Sorting the file names. Shell wildcards and the `ls` command do that.
3. Calling [`stat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)) to retrieve metadata about each directory entry, such as whether it is a directory.

#3 is the most expensive by far, because it requires loading an inode for each file. In comparison all the file names needed for #1 are compactly stored in a few blocks. #2 wastes some CPU time but it is often not a deal breaker.

If there are no newlines in file names, a simple `ls -A | wc -l` tells you how many files there are in the directory. Beware that if you have an alias for `ls`, this may trigger a call to `stat` (e.g. `ls --color` or `ls -F` need to know the file type, which requires a call to `stat`), so from the command line, call `command ls -A | wc -l` or `\ls -A | wc -l` to avoid an alias.

If there are newlines in the file name, whether newlines are listed or not depends on the Unix variant. GNU coreutils and BusyBox default to displaying `?` for a newline, so they're safe.

Call `ls -f` to list the entries without sorting them (#2). This automatically turns on `-a` (at least on modern systems). The `-f` option is in POSIX but with optional status; most implementations support it, but not BusyBox. The option `-q` replaces non-printable characters including newlines by `?`; it's POSIX but isn't supported by BusyBox, so omit it if you need BusyBox support at the expense of overcounting files whose name contains a newline character.

If the directory has no subdirectories, then most versions of `find` will not call `stat` on its entries (leaf directory optimization: a directory that has a link count of 2 cannot have subdirectories, so `find` doesn't need to look up the metadata of the entries unless a condition such as `-type` requires it). So `find . | wc -l` is a portable, fast way to count files in a directory provided that the directory has no subdirectories and that no file name contains a newline.

If the directory has no subdirectories but file names may contain newlines, try one of these (the second one should be faster if it's supported, but may not be noticeably so).

```
find -print0 | tr -dc \\0 | wc -c
find -printf a | wc -c
```

On the other hand, don't use `find` if the directory has subdirectories: even `find . -maxdepth 1` calls `stat` on every entry (at least with GNU find and BusyBox find). You avoid sorting (#2) but you pay the price of an inode lookup (#3) which kills performance.

In the shell without external tools, you can run count the files in the current directory with `set -- *; echo $#`. This misses dot files (files whose name begins with `.`) and reports 1 instead of 0 in an empty directory. This is the fastest way to count files in small directories because it doesn't require starting an external program, but (except in zsh) wastes time for larger directories due to the sorting step (#2).

- In bash, this is a reliable way to count the files in the current directory:

  ```
  shopt -s dotglob nullglob
  a=(*)
  echo ${#a[@]}
  ```
- In ksh93, this is a reliable way to count the files in the current directory:

  ```
  FIGNORE='@(.|..)'
  a=(~(N)*)
  echo ${#a[@]}
  ```
- In zsh, this is a reliable way to count the files in the current directory:

  ```
  a=(*(DNoN))
  echo $#a
  ```

  If you have the `mark_dirs` option set, make sure to turn it off: `a=(*(DNoN^M))`.
- In any POSIX shell, this is a reliable way to count the files in the current directory:

  ```
  total=0
  set -- *
  if [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ -e "$1" ] || [ -L "$1" ]; then total=$((total+$#)); fi
  set -- .[!.]*
  if [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ -e "$1" ] || [ -L "$1" ]; then total=$((total+$#)); fi
  set -- ..?*
  if [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ -e "$1" ] || [ -L "$1" ]; then total=$((total+$#)); fi
  echo "$total"
  ```

All of these methods sort the file names, except for the zsh one.

Comment: My empirical testing on >1 million files shows that `find -maxdepth 1` easily keeps pace with `\ls -U` as long as you don't add anything like a `-type` declaration that has to do further checks. Are you sure GNU find actually calls `stat`? Even the slowdown on `find -type` is nothing compared to how much `ls -l` bogs if you make it return file details. On the other hand the clear speed winner is `zsh` using the non sorting glob. (sorted globs are 2x slower than `ls` while the non-sorting one is 2x faster). I wonder if file system types would significantly effect these results.

Comment: @Caleb I ran `strace`. This is only true if the directory has subdirectories: otherwise `find`'s leaf directory optimization kicks in (even without `-maxdepth 1`), I should have mentioned that. A lot of things can affect the result, including the filesystem type (calling `stat` is a lot more expensive on filesystems that represent directories as linear lists than on filesystems that represent directories as trees), whether the inodes were all created together and are thus close by on the disk, cold or hot cache, etc.

Comment: Historically, `ls -f` has been the reliable way to prevent calling `stat` - this is often simply described today as "output is not sorted" (which it also causes), and does include `.` and `..`. `-A` and `-U` are not standard options.

Comment: If you specifically want to count file with a common extension (or other string), inserting that into the command eliminates the extra 2.  Here is an example: `\ls -afq *[0-9].pdb | wc -l`

Comment: FYI, with ksh93  `version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01` on my Debian-based system, `FIGNORE` doesn't seem to work. The `.` and `..` entries are included into the resulting array

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy The pattern was missing one character. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: See also `n=0; : *(N^e:'((++n))':)` in `zsh` to avoid storing the list of files.

Comment: Note that not all directories are guaranteed to contain a `.` and `..` entry. So subtracting 2 unconditionally may be wrong in some contexts.

Answer (score 21):

```
find /foo/foo2/ -maxdepth 1 | wc -l
```

Is considerably faster on my machine but the local `.` directory is added to the count.

Comment: Thanks. I'm compelled to ask a silly question though: why is it faster?  Because it's not bothering to look-up file attributes?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding. As long as your not using the `-type` parameter `find` should be faster than `ls`

Comment: Hmmm.... if I'm understanding the documentation of _find_ well, this should actually be better than my answer. Anyone with more experience can verify?

Comment: Add a `-mindepth 1` to omit the directory itself.

Answer (score 8):

`ls -1U` before the pipe should spend just a bit less resources, as it does no attempt to sort the file entries, it just reads them as they are sorted in the folder on disk. It also produces less output, meaning slightly less work for `wc`.

You could also use `ls -f` which is more or less a shortcut for `ls -1aU`.

I don't know if there is a resource-efficient way to do it via a command without piping though.

Comment: Btw, -1 is implied when the output goes to a pipe

Comment: @enzotib - it is? Wow... one learns something new every day!

Answer (score 6):

Another point of comparison. While not being a shell oneliner, this C program doesn't do anything superflous. Note that hidden files are ignored to match the output of `ls|wc -l` (`ls -l|wc -l` is off by one due to the total blocks in the first line of output).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int file_count = 0;
    DIR * dirp;
    struct dirent * entry;

    if (argc < 2)
        error(EXIT_FAILURE, 0, "missing argument");

    if(!(dirp = opendir(argv[1])))
        error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "could not open '%s'", argv[1]);

    while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_name[0] == '.') { /* ignore hidden files */
            continue;
        }
        file_count++;
    }
    closedir(dirp);

    printf("%d\n", file_count);
}
```

Comment: Using the `readdir()` stdio API does add some overhead and does not give you control over the size of the buffer passed to the underlying system call (`getdents` on Linux)

Answer (score 4):

You could try `perl -e 'opendir($dh,".");$i=0;while(readdir $dh){$i++};print "$i\n";'`

It'd be interesting to compare timings with your shell pipe.

Comment: On my tests, this keeps pretty much exactly the same pace as the three other fastest solutions (`find -maxdepth 1 | wc -l`, `\ls -AU | wc -l` and the `zsh` based non sorting glob and array count). In other words it beats out the options with various inefficiencies such as sorting or reading extraneous file properties. I would venture to say since it doesn't earn you anything either, it isn't worth using over a simpler solution unless you happen to be in perl already :)

Comment: Note that this will include the `.` and `..` directory entries in the count, so you need to subtract two to get the actual number of files (and subdirectories). In modern Perl, `perl -E 'opendir $dh, "."; $i++ while readdir $dh; say $i - 2'` would do it.

Comment: @doneal24 The `closedir` instruction is missing in your perl oneliner, is it done implicitly ?

Comment: @SebMa Yes. In general when any program exits all open file (including directory) descriptors are closed. It is better programming practice to explicitly close everything but this is often ignored.

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120078/47538), I can think of this one as a possible solution.

```c
/*
 * List directories using getdents() because ls, find and Python libraries
 * use readdir() which is slower (but uses getdents() underneath.
 *
 * Compile with 
 * ]$ gcc  getdents.c -o getdents
 */
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>     /* Defines DT_* constants */
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define handle_error(msg) \
       do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

struct linux_dirent {
   long           d_ino;
   off_t          d_off;
   unsigned short d_reclen;
   char           d_name[];
};

#define BUF_SIZE 1024*1024*5

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int fd, nread;
   char buf[BUF_SIZE];
   struct linux_dirent *d;
   int bpos;
   char d_type;

   fd = open(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : ".", O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY);
   if (fd == -1)
       handle_error("open");

   for ( ; ; ) {
       nread = syscall(SYS_getdents, fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
       if (nread == -1)
           handle_error("getdents");

       if (nread == 0)
           break;

       for (bpos = 0; bpos < nread;) {
           d = (struct linux_dirent *) (buf + bpos);
           d_type = *(buf + bpos + d->d_reclen - 1);
           if( d->d_ino != 0 && d_type == DT_REG ) {
              printf("%s\n", (char *)d->d_name );
           }
           bpos += d->d_reclen;
       }
   }

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Copy the C program above into directory in which the files need to be listed. Then execute these commands:

```bsh
gcc getdents.c -o getdents
./getdents | wc -l
```

Comment: A few things: 1) if you're willing to use a custom program for this, you might as well just count the files and print the count; 2) to compare with `ls -f`, don't filter on `d_type` at all, just on `d->d_ino != 0`; 3) subtract 2 for `.` and `..`.

Comment: See linked answer for a timings example where this is 40x faster than the accepted `ls -f`.

Answer (score 1):

A bash-only solution, not requiring any external program, but don't know how much efficient:

```
list=(*)
echo "${#list[@]}"
```

Comment: Glob expansion isn't necessary the most resource efficient way to do this. Besides most shells having an upper limit to the number of items they will even process so this will probably bomb when dealing with a million plus items, it also sorts the output. The solutions involving find or ls without sorting options will be faster.

Comment: @Caleb, only old versions of ksh had such limits (and didn't support that syntax) AFAIK. In all most other shells, the limit is just the available memory. You've got a point that it's going to be very inefficient, especially in bash.

Answer (score 1):

os.listdir() in python can do the work for you. It gives an array of the contents of the directory, excluding the special '.' and '..' files. Also, no need to worry abt files with special characters like '\n' in the name.

```
python -c 'import os;print len(os.listdir("."))'
```

following is the time taken by the above python command compared with the 'ls -Af' command.

```
~/test$ time ls -Af |wc -l
399144

real    0m0.300s
user    0m0.104s
sys     0m0.240s
~/test$ time python -c 'import os;print len(os.listdir("."))'
399142

real    0m0.249s
user    0m0.064s
sys     0m0.180s
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the *most* resource efficient way would involve no outside process invocations. So I'd wager on...

```
cglb() ( c=0 ; set --
    tglb() { [ -e "$2" ] || [ -L "$2" ] &&
       c=$(($c+$#-1))
    }
    for glb in '.?*' \*
    do  tglb $1 ${glb##.*} ${glb#\*}
        set -- ..
    done
    echo $c
)
```

Comment: Got relative numbers? for how many files?

Answer (score 1):

*A bit late answer (after 6 years), but...*

The **fastest** way is just do `ls -l` **on the parent directory**, and check link-counts column for the given subdir.

Demo: Let say, want count the number of files/dirs in my `/usr/lib` directory.

So, entering `ls -l /usr` produces:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  978 root  wheel  31296 29 apr  2019 bin
drwxr-xr-x  267 root  wheel   8544 30 okt  2018 include
drwxr-xr-x  312 root  wheel   9984 23 jan  2019 lib
drwxr-xr-x  240 root  wheel   7680 29 apr  2019 libexec
drwxr-xr-x   17 root  wheel    544 14 nov  2018 local
drwxr-xr-x  248 root  wheel   7936 23 jan  2019 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   47 root  wheel   1504  4 okt  2018 share
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  wheel    160 25 okt  2017 standalone
```

The number just after the permissions is the `link count` of the file. For a directory it is just the number of entries inside it. So, in above example the `/usr/lib` has **312** entries.

Let verify:

```
$ ls -1a /usr/lib | wc -l
     312
```

Without showing the other directories in the parent, just use `-d` e.g.

```
$ ls -ld /usr/lib
drwxr-xr-x  312 root  wheel  9984 23 jan  2019 /usr/lib
#           ^^^ - the number of entries in the /usr/lib (including . and ..)
```

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the issue from @Joel 's answer, where it added `.` as a file:

`find /foo/foo2 -maxdepth 1 | tail -n +2 | wc -l`

`tail` simply removes the first line, meaning that `.` isn't counted anymore.

Comment: Adding a pair of pipes in order to omit one line of `wc` input is not very efficient as the [overhead increases linearly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) with regard to input size. In this case, why not simply decrement the final count to compensate for it being off by one, which is a constant time operation: `echo $(( $(find /foo/foo2 -maxdepth 1 | wc -l) - 1))`

Comment: Rather than feed that much data through another process, it would probably be better to just do some math on the final output. `let count = $(find /foo/foo2 -maxdepth 1 | wc -l) - 2`

Answer (score 0):

`ls -1 | wc -l` comes immediately to my mind.  Whether `ls -1U` is faster than `ls -1` is purely academic - the difference should be negligible but for very large directories.

Answer (score 0):

To *exclude subdirectories* from the count, here's a variation on the accepted answer from Gilles:

```
echo $(( $( \ls -afq target | wc -l ) - $( \ls -od target | cut -f2 -d' ') ))
```

The outer `$(( ))` arithmetic expansion subtracts the output of the second `$( )` subshell from the first `$( )`. The first `$( )` is exactly Gilles' from above. The second `$( )` outputs the count of directories "linking" to the target. This comes from `ls -od` (substitute `ls -ld` if desired), where the column that lists the count of hard links has that as a special meaning for directories. The "link" count includes `.`, `..`, and any subdirectories.

I didn't test performance, but it would seem to be similar. It adds a stat of the target directory, and some overhead for the added subshell and pipe.

Answer (score -3):

I would think echo * would be more efficient than any 'ls' command:

```
echo * | wc -w
```

Comment: What about files with a space in their name? `echo 'Hello World'|wc -w` produces `2`.

Comment: @JosephR. Caveat Emptor