# The ls command is not working for a directory with a huge number of files

Tags: ls

I had a directory which had around **5 million** files. When I tried to run the `ls` command from inside this directory, my system consumed a huge amount of memory and it hung after sometime. Is there an efficient way to list the files other than using the `ls` command?

Comment: Make sure you don't have an alias for `ls` that uses `--color` or `-F` as that would mean doing a `lstat(2)` for each file.

Comment: By the way, storing millions of files in a single directory is a rather bad idea. If you control the directory layout, perhaps split it by some criteria?

Comment: Was that a pure `ls` call or did you use options?

Comment: It was a pure ls call.

Comment: @d33tah Yeah, 5 million is a lot!  My root file system has a limit of 7 million inodes.

Comment: You can tune that limit while creating the filesystem, but still - as far as I know, most filesystems aren't optimized for handling millions of files in a single directory. I suggest to split them.

Comment: 5 million items to output -how are you looking at this - simple listing is too much to see - so what do you want the listing for?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`ls` actually sorts the files and tries to list them which becomes a huge overhead if we are trying to list more than a million files inside a directory. As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427032/fast-linux-file-count-for-a-large-number-of-files) link, we can use `strace` or `find` to list the files. However, those options also seemed unfeasible to my problem since I had 5 million files. After some bit of googling, I found that if we list  the directories using `getdents()`, it is supposed to be faster, because `ls`, `find` and `Python` libraries use `readdir()` which is slower but uses `getdents()` underneath.

We can find the C code to list the files using `getdents()` from [here](https://github.com/aidenbell/getdents/blob/master/src/getdents.c):

```
/*
 * List directories using getdents() because ls, find and Python libraries
 * use readdir() which is slower (but uses getdents() underneath.
 *
 * Compile with 
 * ]$ gcc  getdents.c -o getdents
 */
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>     /* Defines DT_* constants */
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define handle_error(msg) \
       do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

struct linux_dirent {
   long           d_ino;
   off_t          d_off;
   unsigned short d_reclen;
   char           d_name[];
};

#define BUF_SIZE 1024*1024*5

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int fd, nread;
   char buf[BUF_SIZE];
   struct linux_dirent *d;
   int bpos;
   char d_type;

   fd = open(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : ".", O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY);
   if (fd == -1)
       handle_error("open");

   for ( ; ; ) {
       nread = syscall(SYS_getdents, fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
       if (nread == -1)
           handle_error("getdents");

       if (nread == 0)
           break;

       for (bpos = 0; bpos < nread;) {
           d = (struct linux_dirent *) (buf + bpos);
           d_type = *(buf + bpos + d->d_reclen - 1);
           if( d->d_ino != 0 && d_type == DT_REG ) {
              printf("%s\n", (char *)d->d_name );
           }
           bpos += d->d_reclen;
       }
   }

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Copy the C program above into directory in which the files need to be listed. Then execute the below commands.

```
gcc  getdents.c -o getdents
./getdents
```

*Timings example*: `getdents` can be much faster than `ls -f`, depending on the system configuration. Here are some timings demonstrating a 40x speed increase for listing a directory containing about 500k files over an NFS mount in a compute cluster. Each command was run 10 times in immediate succession, first `getdents`, then `ls -f`. The first run is significantly slower than all others, probably due to NFS caching page faults. (Aside: over this mount, the `d_type` field is unreliable, in the sense that many files appear as "unknown" type.)

```
command: getdents $bigdir
usr:0.08 sys:0.96  wall:280.79 CPU:0%
usr:0.06 sys:0.18  wall:0.25   CPU:97%
usr:0.05 sys:0.16  wall:0.21   CPU:99%
usr:0.04 sys:0.18  wall:0.23   CPU:98%
usr:0.05 sys:0.20  wall:0.26   CPU:99%
usr:0.04 sys:0.18  wall:0.22   CPU:99%
usr:0.04 sys:0.17  wall:0.22   CPU:99%
usr:0.04 sys:0.20  wall:0.25   CPU:99%
usr:0.06 sys:0.18  wall:0.25   CPU:98%
usr:0.06 sys:0.18  wall:0.25   CPU:98%
command: /bin/ls -f $bigdir
usr:0.53 sys:8.39  wall:8.97   CPU:99%
usr:0.53 sys:7.65  wall:8.20   CPU:99%
usr:0.44 sys:7.91  wall:8.36   CPU:99%
usr:0.50 sys:8.00  wall:8.51   CPU:100%
usr:0.41 sys:7.73  wall:8.15   CPU:99%
usr:0.47 sys:8.84  wall:9.32   CPU:99%
usr:0.57 sys:9.78  wall:10.36  CPU:99%
usr:0.53 sys:10.75 wall:11.29  CPU:99%
usr:0.46 sys:8.76  wall:9.25   CPU:99%
usr:0.50 sys:8.58  wall:9.13   CPU:99%
```

Comment: Could you add a small benchmark in timing for which your case does display with `ls`?

Comment: Sweet.  And you could add an option to simply count the entries (files) rather than listing their names (saving millions of calls to printf, for this listing).

Comment: Since the directory has millions of files, you could use puts((char*)d->d_name) rather than printf, so save some processing -- see: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/527094-puts-vs-printf

Comment: You know your directory is too big when you have to write custom code to list its contents...

Comment: @casey Except you don't have to.  All this talk about `getdents` vs `readdir` misses the point.

Comment: Come on! It's already got 5 million files in there.  Put your custom "ls" program into some other directory.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill Because of the way piping works, that's not really necessary. You could just `./getdents /my/huge/dir | wc -l` and it will still be pretty fast. That's because you are giving the output of `getdents` to `wc` instead of the `stdout` (terminal in most cases)

Comment: Not a C programmer...any chance somebody can update this so it has glob support? I'm currently piping results through grep, but that seems awfully suboptimal.

Comment: Is it expected that this would do very weird things in an sshfs-mounted directory? I'm getting back a fraction of the results I expect.

Comment: @Ramesh Good one !! Is there any way to get the file properties like date modified , size etc .

Answer (score 95):

Avoid sorting by using:

```
ls --sort=none # "do not sort; list entries in directory order"
```

Or, equivalently:

```
ls -U
```

Comment: I wonder how much overhead the column layout adds, too.  Adding the `-1` flag could help.

Comment: Probably not much, but every little bit helps, right? :)

Comment: @Mikel Is that just a guess, or have you measured that? To me it seems that `-1` takes even longer.

Comment: "-1" helps quite a bit. "ls -f -1" will avoid any stat calls and print everything immediately. The column output (which is the default when sending to a terminal) makes it buffer everything first. On my system, using btrfs in a directory with 8 million files (as created by "seq 1 8000000 | xargs touch"), "time ls -f -1 | wc -l" takes under 5 seconds, while "time ls -f -C | wc -l" takes over 30 seconds.

Comment: @ScottLamb - Your two commands are not a good comparison, because `-C` forces columns - it overrides the default `-1` that is done when piping the output of `ls`. AFAIK, `time ls -f | wc -l` will run just as fast as the `-1` version. Nevertheless I upvoted your comment, because when displaying straight to terminal, it is useful: immediately start seeing some filenames.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The default behavior (`-C` when stdout is a terminal, `-1` when it's a pipe) is confusing. When you're experimenting and measuring, you flip between seeing the output (to ensure the command is doing what you expect) and suppressing it (to avoid the confounding factor of the terminal application's throughput). Better to use commands that behave in the same way in both modes, so explicitly define the output format via `-1`, `-C`, `-l`, etc.

Comment: @ScottLamb - I understand.  I realized later that you were deliberately doing the test with `| wc -l` as a convenience for timing, but that you were doing so to discuss the underlying performance *with or without* the pipe (without => `-C` is the default behavior as you say); you were showing that if columns were being formed, the command was much slower for many files. Thank you.

Comment: This is the working solution. Thanks.

Comment: A great answer!

Comment: @ScottLamb's `ls -f -1` command resulted in actually seeing output instead of either waiting for a very long time or getting an out of memory error. thanks!

Answer (score 19):

The most likely reason why it is slow is file type colouring, you can avoid this with `\ls` or `/bin/ls` turning off the colour options.

If you really have so many files in a dir, using `find` instead is also a good option.

Comment: I don't think this should have been downvoted.  Sorting is one problem, but even without sorting, `ls -U --color` would take a long time since it would `stat` each file.  So both are correct.

Comment: Turning coloring off has a huge impact on the performance of `ls` and it is aliased by default in many many `.bashrc`s out there.

Comment: Yup I did a `/bin/ls -U` and got output in no time, compared to waiting for a very long time before

Comment: Late comment, using `find` would take forever as well.

Answer (score -4):

I find that `echo *` works much faster than ls.  YMMV.

Comment: The shell will sort the `*`.  So this way is probably still very slow for 5 million files.

Comment: @Mikel More than that, I'm pretty sure that 5 million files is over the point where globbing will break entirely.

Comment: Minimum file name length (for 5 million files) is 3 characters (maybe 4 if you stick to more common characters) plus delimiters = 4 chars per file, i.e 20 MB of command arguments. That is well over the common 2MB expanded command line length.  Exec (and even the builtins) would baulk.