# "Display all <num> possibilities? (y or n)" for ls command

Tags: ls

When I attempt to tab complete a filename in the bash prompt, and the output would be many (>100) filenames, the shell asks `Display all <num> possibilities? (y or n)`

**Can I replicate this behaviour with the normal `ls` command?**

I have a directory with >400k files. Accidentally `ls`ing this directory leaves me with an unresponsive shell for many minutes while it spews output. `Ctrl-C` doesn't stop the flood.

Comment: See also [The ls command is not working for a directory with a huge number of files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120077)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*My solution might be a little heavy but well, who knows.*

The problem is that, in order to do that, you would need to count files... which is usually done with:

```
$ ls | wc -l
```

Now, because the content is written to a pipe, and not to stdout, this will take a little less time to complete (writing to a terminal takes a little bit of time, which can become significant with 400k calls to [`write(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write)). It might still take some time, but nevertheless, you could implement this with a simple test:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIMIT=1000
n=$(ls "$@" 2>/dev/null | head -n$LIMIT | wc -l)

if [ $n -ge $LIMIT ]; then
    echo "This directory contains more than $LIMIT entries."
    echo -n "Are you sure want to continue? (y/N) "

    read confirm
    if [ "$confirm" = "y" -o "$confirm" = "Y" ]; then
        exec ls "$@"
    fi
else
    exec ls "$@"
fi
```

Then, just set an alias in your `.bashrc` file, to call this script instead of `/bin/ls`:

```
alias ls='/path/to/my_ls.sh --color=auto'
```

Also make sure it is properly chmoded:

```
$ chmod +x /path/to/my_ls.sh
```

*Edit:* I added a call to `head` so that `ls` is terminated after `$LIMIT` lines of output. This should save some time (and actually make it a better solution that the `timeout` one) ;)

Another approach I would suggest is to use a timeout. If `ls` doesn't complete in say 5s, it should stop and ask you if you're sure about it. Here's a example script (valid for several commands, not just `ls`) :

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                

TIMEOUT=5

if [ $# -le 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [command]"
    exit 1
fi

# Try it silently for a few seconds...
timeout $TIMEOUT "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -eq 124 ]; then
    echo -n "Your command failed to run under "$TIMEOUT"s. "
    echo -n "Retry without a timeout? (y/N) "

    read confirm
    if [ "$confirm" = "y" -o "$confirm" = "Y" ]; then
        exec "$@"
    fi
else
    exec "$@"
fi
```

Then you could set a few aliases, such as:

```
alias ls='/path/to/script.sh ls --color=auto'
alias grep='/path/to/script.sh grep --color=auto'
alias cat='/path/to/script.sh cat'
```

Note that I'm testing `$? -eq 124` because...

> If the command times out, and `--preserve-status` is not set, then exit with status 124.

See [`timeout(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) for more information.