# Unzip to a folder with the same name as the file (without the .zip extension)

Tags: directory, zip

How to unzip a file (ex: `foo.zip`) to a folder with the same name (`foo/`)?

Basically, I want to create an alias of unzip that unzips files into a folder with the same name (instead of the current folder). That's how Mac's unzip utility works and I want to do the same in CLI.

Comment: @Christopher I don't see how it's a duplicate. Can you find an answer to my question in that question?

Comment: The [accepted anwer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317792/90054) answers your question: `unzip -d foo foo.zip`.

Comment: @Fabby, no it doesn't, I need a dynamic solution that won't require adding the name of the target folder. I believe the second paragraph makes this very clear.

Comment: It seems to me that [another answer there, by n.st](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317730/117549) does what you want?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I use [`unar`](https://theunarchiver.com/command-line) for this; by default, if an archive contains more than one top-level file or directory, it creates a directory to store the extracted contents, named after the archive in the way you describe:

```
unar foo.zip
```

You can force the creation of a directory in all cases with the `-d` option:

```
unar -d foo.zip
```

Alternatively, a function can do this with `unzip`:

```
unzd() {
    if [[ $# != 1 ]]; then echo I need a single argument, the name of the archive to extract; return 1; fi
    target="${1%.zip}"
    unzip "$1" -d "${target##*/}"
}
```

The

```
target=${1%.zip}
```

line removes the `.zip` extension, with no regard for anything else (so `foo.zip` becomes `foo`, and `~/foo.zip` becomes `~/foo`). The

```
${target##*/}
```

[parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) removes anything up to the last `/`, so `~/foo` becomes `foo`. This means that the function extracts any `.zip` file to a directory named after it, in the current directory. Use `unzip $1 -d "${target}"` if you want to extract the archive to a directory alongside it instead.

`unar` is available for macOS (along with its GUI application, [The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com/)), Windows, and Linux; it is packaged in many distributions, *e.g.* `unar` in Debian and derivatives, Fedora and derivatives, `community/unarchiver` in Arch Linux.

Comment: Smoothing over this behavior for unzip, 7z, unrar, etc is just crazy....glad to see unar can just do it all (I run `parallel unar {} ::: *.zip *.rar *.7z`)

Comment: `unar` is perfect.

Answer (score 25):

Just one another variant to do that with a 1-liner for multiple zip files in current dir:

```
for f in *.zip; do unzip "$f" -d "${f%.zip}"; done
```

For just one file (i.e. to use in a function) it would be:

```
unzip "$1" -d "${1%.zip}"
```

Answer (score 23):

Use *unzip -d exdir zipfile.zip* to extract a zipfile into a particular directory. In principle from reading your post literally you could write a function like this:

```
unzip_d () {
    unzip -d "$1" "$1"
}
```

Since you want the *.zip* extension removed though, you can use special variable syntax to do that:

```
unzip_d () {
    zipfile="$1"
    zipdir=${1%.zip}
    unzip -d "$zipdir" "$zipfile"
}
```

Comment: additional tip: use [basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) to make it more robust. (already upvoted though)  **;-)